# Getting a Screenshot of a Google Map in Flex (Security Error Workaround)

Tags: security, google-maps, apache-flex

I have a Google map in my flex app that I need to occasionally export to an image file. Every time I try to call the, Map.getPrintableBitmap() or ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData() functions I get the Error #2123: Security sandbox violation.

I've tried adding various security allowances like:

```
Security.allowDomain("*.google.com"); 
Security.allowDomain("*.googleapis.com");
```

and forcing the app to read Google's crossdomain:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mt0.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mt1.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml");
```

...and it makes no difference.

My biggest question is: **WHY IS THE APP TRYING TO ACCESS A REMOTE FILE AT ALL??**
I'm asking for a bitmap representation of a component that's already been drawn on the client's screen. Clearly all the information necessary to provide that bitmap is already present in local memory.

Anyways, has anyone found a workaround for this?

I'm using version 1.20 of Google Maps for Flex.

Here's some example code that should reproduce the error I'm getting. Note: it requires the Google Maps for Flex library to be installed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"


               initialize="initComp()">

<mx:Canvas id="mapContainer" x="100" y="100" width="980" height="620" >
        </mx:Canvas>

<mx:Button label="Try Export" click="exportMap()" />




<fx:Script><![CDATA[
    import com.google.maps.Map;

    import mx.graphics.codec.PNGEncoder;

    private var gMap:Map;

private function initComp():void{
    gMap = new Map();
    gMap.sensor = "false";
    Security.allowInsecureDomain("*.google.com");
    Security.allowInsecureDomain("*.googleapis.com"); 

    //local debug
    gMap.key = //"[API KEY]";



    gMap.width = 980;
    gMap.height = 620;

    mapContainer.addChild(gMap);
}

public function exportMap():void{
    /*Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mt0.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://mt1.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.google.com/crossdomain.xml");
    Security.loadPolicyFile("http://maps.googleapis.com/crossdomain.xml");*/
    //var snapshot:BitmapData = ImageSnapshot.captureBitmapData(mapComponent);

    var snapshot:BitmapData = gMap.getPrintableBitmap().bitmapData;
    var encoder:PNGEncoder = new PNGEncoder();
    var pngData:ByteArray = encoder.encode(snapshot);

    var ref:FileReference = new FileReference();
    //ref.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onFileSaveError);
    ref.save(pngData, "OneView-Map.png");
}

]]></fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: if you try to grab an image snapshot the outer container / component do you get the same issue?

Answer (score 2):

I have gone through the same issue for some time and then found out the reason.

Flash has a strict "**Cross-domain restriction**". You cant access resources outside our domain for some reason { like : .swf, images/.png.. ,} . Saying you can view the resources by loading them into a LOADER, But not extract them.

The work around for this is to pull those resources through a **PHP Proxy script**.

I can see many questions arising from you. The Below links have helped me solve this problem, hope it does for you too.

**How to use proxy to import resources from other domains**
http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-using-a-php-proxy-to-load-assets-into-flash/

**Proxy trick for .swf s**
http://jorgealbaladejo.com/2010/09/06/actionscript-and-cross-domain-problem/

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the loaded content as the source to an Image that has trustContent set to "true", then get an ImageSnapshot of that.  This will force the policy file to be read specifically for the content of that Image.

HTH;

Amy

Comment: mx.controls.Image will take any DisplayObject as its source, and trustContent will force the policy file to be read for whatever is being displayed in the control.  I am not using Google maps, so that's absolutely as much specificity as I can give without more code from you.

Comment: So you'd have an Image and set its source property to gMap and set trustContent on it to true.  Then take an ImageSnapshot of it.  Finally, you'll need to add it back as a child of your mapContainer, since setting it as the source of the Image adds it as a child to something that's inside the Image control.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just try to draw the map itself into a BitmapData?

```
var bitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(gMap.width, gMap.height);
bitmap.draw(gMap);
```

I'm not sure why you're getting a security sandbox violation unless you're doing something funky.  Are you running the file locally? Have you tried using it from a web server?

Comment: No matter how I try to grab the bitmap, it always ends up calling BitMapData.draw() and then having an error.

Comment: If I use your way or the captureBitmapData function, it works locally but fails on any server. If I use google's built in getPrintableBitmap() function, it fails in all modes. Somehow, the BitampData class is trying to redraw the map with fresh tiles from the Google server instead of using the screen pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Google's answer is, 'Use the Flex 3 SDK, not Flex 4." Thanks a lot Google.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use:

```
var bitmap:Bitmap = googleMap.getPrintableBitmap();
```